# opening a url instead of document form in LN embedded view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I know this is a bit old Lotus Notes question but I will still ask this here since I haven't found any solution on the web about my query. 
I have an embedded view in a form that I launch in via web, what I want to do is when I click on a record on the embedded view instead of opening the document of that form, it will open another form that contains another embedded view. I hope my question is clear enough for everyone to understand, but if its not I will revise it if needed.
Is this possible or not? thank you in advance.

I haven't tried this ever since. So sorry if it's a bit newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you want to open the document with another form or if you want to open another form only...

If you want to open the document with another form: 
In the embedded view you can specify a form formuly in Domino Designer. Type in the name of the form that you want to open and from nowon all documents will open with the form specified here. Of course you can alos specify more complex formulas with certain conditions.

If you just want to open another form you can change the link column with html code to generate a link. The HTML must be specified in sqared brackets. The following sample generates a link o http://www.openntf.org in a column of a notes view.

```
"[<a href=\"http://www.openntf.org\">custom link label</a>]"
```

**Updated:** use field value as link label
sample to open a form in another database (just replace ,  and  with real values):

```
"[<a href=\"http://<yourserver>/<yourdatabasepath>/<formname>?openform\">" + <yourfieldnamehere> + "</a>]"
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that the form I'm trying to open is from another database, is it possible in form formula in the embedded view or not?

Comment: Wow, that was very helpful thanks a lot! Hmm.. I think it will work for me but can I change the "custom link to.." text with a field value?

Comment: please check my updated link above. And feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to change the "Form"- formula of the embedded view to use the new form when clicking the link.

Comment: Oh! Goodness me I haven't thought about that! XD thank you Torsten I will try that one out. :)